# Unable to find module/folder despite being in the directory

Tags: python, path, tracking, yolo, sys

I run tracking Yolov5 + StrongSort and Yolov7 + StrongSort and they have structure:

```
> yolov5
> yolov7
> strongsort
main.py
```

And I connect them with the code in the main.py like this:

```
FILE = Path(__file__).resolve()
ROOT = FILE.parents[0]  # yolov5 strongsort root directory
WEIGHTS = ROOT / 'weights'

if str(ROOT) not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT))  # add ROOT to PATH
if str(ROOT / 'yolov5') not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT / 'yolov5'))  # add yolov7 ROOT to PATH
if str(ROOT / 'yolov7') not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT / 'yolov7'))  # add yolov7 ROOT to PATH
if str(ROOT / 'strong_sort') not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(str(ROOT / 'strong_sort'))  # add strong_sort ROOT to PATH
ROOT = Path(os.path.relpath(ROOT, Path.cwd()))  # relative
```

code I take from 2 link github: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet, https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov7_StrongSORT_OSNet. When i take model from yolov7 like this:

```
model = attempt_load('model/yolov7.pt', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
print(model)
```

They have error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.google_utils'`. I understand they use attempt_load in yolov5 and not use yolov7. Help me pls about this problem

Answer (score 0):

Yolov7 model is loaded by:

https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/yolov7/blob/60978d6acd409cb8089d44813659ced59d41aa96/models/experimental.py#L237

Yolov5 is loaded by:

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/91a81d48fa4e34dbdbaf0e45a1f841c11216aab5/models/experimental.py#L73

This means that both `attempt_load` are different. Yolov5's cannot be used to load Yolov7 and vice-versa.